# Optimize "1D" bin packing/sheet cutting

Tags: optaplanner

Our use case could be described as a variant of 1D bin packing or sheet cutting.
Imagine a drywall with a beam framing.
We want to optimize the number and size of gypsum boards that would be needed to cover the wall.
Boards must start and end on a beam.
Boards must not overlap (hard constraint).
Less (i.e. bigger) boards, the better (soft constraint).

What we currently do:

1. Pre-generate all possible boards and pass them as problem facts.
2. Let the solver pick the best subset of those (nullable planning variable).
3. First Fit Decreasing + Simulated Annealing

Even relatively small walls (~6m, less than 20 possible boards to pick from) take sometimes minutes and while we mostly get a feasible solution, it's rarely optimal.

Is there a better way to model that?

**EDIT**

Our current domain model looks like the following. Please note that the planning entity only holds the selected/picked material but nothing else. I.e. currently our planning entities are all equal, which kind of prevents any optimization that depends on planning entity difficulty.

```kotlin
data class Assignment(

    @PlanningId
    private val id: Long? = null,

    @PlanningVariable(
        valueRangeProviderRefs = ["materials"],
        strengthComparatorClass = MaterialStrengthComparator::class,
        nullable = true
    )
    var material: Material? = null
)

data class Material(
    val start: Double,
    val stop: Double,
)
```

Comment: What's your score calculation speed? And what score director are you using to achieve it?

Comment: We're using the stream based constraint calculation, i.e. the incremental one. The speed is somewhere around 5k/s more or less, but always below 10k from what I remember seeing in the last days during testing.

Comment: 10k is what we suggest as the minimum to be able to get the most out of OptaPlanner. However, besides that and Geoffrey's answer, no one will be able to give you a less generic answer, unless they understand your model and your constraints.

Comment: Can you add a toy problem with actual data?
I don't understand the dry wall isolation business enough to create data to play with

Answer (score 1):

Active (sub)**pillar** change and swap move selectors. See optaplanner docs section about move selectors (move neighorhoods). The default moves (single swap and single change) are probably getting stuck in local optima (and even though SA helps them escape those, those escapes are probably not efficient enough).

That should help, but a custom move to swap two subpillars of the almost the same size, might improve efficiency further.

Also, as you're using SA (Simulated Annealing), know that SA is parameter sensitive. Use optaplanner-benchmark to try multiple SA starting temp parameters with different dataset set sizes. Also compare it to a plain LA (Late Acceptance) in benchmarks too. LA isn't fickle like SA can be. (With  fickle I don't mean unstable. I mean potential dataset size sensitive parameter tweaking.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

I added a snippet from our domain model in the original question. From my limited understanding, with our current model the use of pillar-based moves won't work, or will it? 

I tried it and couldn't see a significant improvement.